# Extending Fragment: MainActivity is not an enclosing class when adding JavacriptInterface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-webview

I got the error `MainActivity is not an enclosing class` when I try to `addJavascriptInterface` to the Webview inside the extended Fragment class:

```
mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity.JS_Bind(this, mXWalkView),"Android");
```

In my MainActivity I implented it this way in the onCreate method:

`mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new JS_Bind(this, mXWalkView),"Android");`

And JS_Bind is a public class inside MainActivity:

```
public class JS_Bind {
    private static final String TAG = "JS_Bind";
    private Context context;
    private XWalkView mXWalkView;

    public JS_Bind(Context c, XWalkView mXWalkView) {
        context = c;
        this.mXWalkView = mXWalkView;
    }

    @org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
    public void makeToast(String toast) {
        Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

Note: I also use [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) (a Webview library). How can I fix this error and what exactly does it mean? I read similiar questions and answers but didn't understand it.

Edit: `Fragment` class:

```
public class SlideFragment extends Fragment {
    private XWalkView mXWalkView;
    private Context c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false);

    }

   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        int position = FragmentPagerItem.getPosition(getArguments());

        XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
        mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity.JS_Bind(this, mXWalkView),"Android");
        mXWalkView = (XWalkView) view.findViewById (R.id.webView);
        mXWalkView.clearCache(true);

        mXWalkView.load(MainActivity.ROOT + "?s=" + getArguments().getString("title") + ".php?page=" + position, null);
```

Comment: What is the declaration of the fragment class?

Comment: I updated the question @Karakuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Fragment` cannot use `this` as a `Context` because `Fragment` does not extend `Context`. Use [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) or [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) instead when calling the constructor for `JS_Bind`.

EDIT

```
mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity.JS_Bind(getActivity(),
        mXWalkView), "Android");
```

Comment: You mean like this? `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();` 
        `mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity.JS_Bind(m.getActivity(), mXWalkView),"Android");` (I'm still a beginner in Java)

Comment: I tried this already. Still the same error: https://picload.org/image/rgwidaii/error.jpg

Comment: @Vaia is `JS_Bind` declared inside of `MainActivity`? If not, get rid of the `MainActivity.` and just call `new JS_Bind`

Comment: Yes, it's declared inside `MainActivity` as a public class

Comment: @Vaia does it need to be? What happens if you just call `new JS_Bind` anyway?

Comment: Then it says `cannot resolve symbol`. I don't know if I have to declare it inside the `MainActivity` or as a seperate class but it's suggested in almost every webview library afaik, if you want to add the JavascriptInterface for your custom Javascript functions

Comment: @Vaia "Cannot resolve symbol" might just mean you forgot an `import` statement.

Comment: Yes, he suggests to import MainActivity, but then it's `mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity.JS_Bind(getActivity(), mXWalkView),"Android");` again